# Mark an ext4 filesystem as read-only

Tags: ext4, readonly

I want to create an ext4 filesystem, and add some files to it, then "freeze" it so it is henceforth read-only.

I know it's possible to use the `ro` mount option. But is there some way to indicate in the filesystem itself that it is read-only?

I see that `tune2fs` has an option `-o` to set default mount options, but `-o ro` is not a valid option.

I also see that `tune2fs` has an option `-E mount_opts`. I tried `-E mount_opts=ro` on a loopback filesystem (Ubuntu 14.10):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=ext4test bs=1M count=32
mkfs.ext4 -L test ext4test
tune2fs -E mount_opts=ro ext4test
mkdir ext4testmnt
sudo mount ext4test ext4testmnt
```

However, the file system is still mounted as read-write.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is supported in recent kernels (4.0 and later) and, since late February 2015, in [`e2fsprogs`](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) (available since version 1.42.13).

With the appropriate kernel and tools, you can flag an `ext4` filesystem read-only using `tune2fs`:

```
tune2fs -O read-only ext4test
```

and clear the flag as always with

```
tune2fs -O ^read-only ext4test
```

Comment: If a filesystem has the read-only flag, it should be possible to see it in the filesystem features with something like `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/ext4test | grep '^Filesystem features'`