# How do we clear the read only flag on ext4 partition

Tags: ext4

I have an android system.img I want to remove the read-only flag so that I can mount and edit it I once saw it somewhere but I can't seem to find the article. maybe it has to do with removing shared_blocks?!
I can `mount -o ro system.img` but when I do `mount -o rw` I get

```
mount: /mnt/system: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
```

I tried `tune2fs -O ^read-only system.img` and `e2fsck -fy -E unshare_blocks system.img` it still doesn't mount rw

Comment: inverse of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208851/mark-an-ext4-filesystem-as-read-only

Comment: Your `system.img` file isn't an `ext4` partition. `ext4` tools won't work. Use `file -k system.img` to investigate. While it's mounted, `mount | grep system`. Read `man mount file`.

Comment: @waltinator it is ext4 formated with EXT4_FEATURE_RO_COMPAT_SHARED_BLOCKS

Answer (score 1):

It turns out [resize2fs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220892/system-partition-locked-to-read-only-in-android-10) temporarily fixes the problem. I had to run `resize2fs system.img size` with a size to grow the partition.

Instead I did grow the partition by double its size and performed
`e2fsck -fy -E unshare_blocks system.img` now when I mount it works fine